# Uploading datas to skydrive without overwriting the existing file content in windows phone8

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I tried to upload data(ie.) add data to an existing file in skydrive but everytime the content has been overwriting.
I want to add datas to the existing file without overwriting the previous contents.

Thanx for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should obtain the LiveConnect SDK, add the APIs to your project, login to the service, and upload a file to Skydrive.

Have a look over these threads. [How to simply access SkyDrive, write and read files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590031) and [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/SkyDrive_-_How_to_upload_content_on_Windows_Phone) one too.